# XML Query to DataGridView using XDocument in C#

Tags: c#, xml, datagridview

My knowledge of using XML in application is very basic, I also searched for many posts for this but I couldn't find what I am looking for.

I am trying to make an application where the user is given an XML file to put it in a certain folder and the application reads its data and bind it to a DataGridView (DGV).

My XML file is like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<Project>

  <PCode>18-01</PCode>
  <PName>Project A</PName>

  <AllBOQ>

      <BOQ Division="Mechanical">
        <Items>
          <Item>
            <Code>M-FF-01</Code>
            <Description>Supply and Install of Seamless Black Steel Pipes, Sch. 40, 1"</Description>
            <Quantity>50</Quantity>
            <Unit>mt</Unit>
          </Item>
          <Item>
            <Code>M-FF-02</Code>
            <Description>Supply and Install of Seamless Black Steel Pipes, Sch. 40, 2"</Description>
            <Quantity>60</Quantity>
            <Unit>mt</Unit>
          </Item>
        </Items>
      </BOQ>

      <BOQ Division="Electrical">
          <Items>
              <Item>
                <Code>E-FA-01</Code>
                <Description>Supply and Install of Fire Alarm</Description>
                <Quantity>15</Quantity>
                <Unit>nr</Unit>
              </Item>
        </Items>
      </BOQ>

  </AllBOQ>

</Project>
```

The application should create 4 columns in the DGV with the following order
"Code" , "Description" , "Quantity" , "Unit"
Then populates them with data using this query

```
    private void lbxDivision_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        // Get selected project XML file
        string selCode = lbxProjects.SelectedValue.ToString();
        lblTest.Text = lbxDivision.Text;
        var boqItems = from itm in selProject.Descendants("BOQ")
                       where itm.Attribute("Division").Value == lbxDivision.Text
                       select new BOQItem()
                       {
                           Code        = itm.Elements("Items").Elements("Item").Elements("Code")       .FirstOrDefault().Value,
                           Description = itm.Elements("Items").Elements("Item").Elements("Description").FirstOrDefault().Value,
                           Quantity    = itm.Elements("Items").Elements("Item").Elements("Quantity")   .FirstOrDefault().Value,
                           Unit        = itm.Elements("Items").Elements("Item").Elements("Unit")       .FirstOrDefault().Value
                       };
        dataGridView1.DataSource = boqItems.ToList();

    }
```

The DGV is creating the 4 columns but its populated with one row of data only despite that `<BOQ Division="Mechanical">` have 2 items

How do I query all items under (code, Description, Quantity, Unit) that have BOQ Division Attribute = "Mechanical" (or according to the user selection)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
        var items = selProject.Descendants("BOQ")
                              .Where(boq => boq.Attribute("Division").Value == lbxDivision.Text)
                              .Descendants("Item")
                              .Select(itm => new BOQItem()
                              {
                                   Code        = itm.Elements("Code")       .FirstOrDefault().Value,
                                   Description = itm.Elements("Description").FirstOrDefault().Value,
                                   Quantity    = itm.Elements("Quantity")   .FirstOrDefault().Value,
                                   Unit        = itm.Elements("Unit")       .FirstOrDefault().Value
                              }).ToList();
```

Comment: What !! just like that. Thanks. Care to explain your code ?

Comment: I'm sorry ;). Your select just was executed once per Devision not per Item. Thats the reason you only received one item, instead of two. In the code above you see the Descendants("Item") so you get every item of the devision.

Comment: I see, that why we needed 2 lambda expression "boq" and "itm"

Comment: Please also bei aware that the query will throw an exception if some of the nodes don't exist